# jquery if condition is not working

Tags: jquery

I tried like this, after 2nd iteration if condition is failing

```
$('#next_page').click(function(){
    t = $('#totalPages').val();
    c = $('#currentPage').val();
    if(! (c > t)){
        var pageNo = parseInt($('#currentPage').val())+1;
        var sector = $('#sectorValue').val();
        var state = $('#states').val();
```

Comment: On a side note, why not replace `if(! (c > t))` with `if (c <= t)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var t = parseInt($('#totalPages').val());
var c = parseInt($('#currentPage').val());
if(! (c > t)){
```

Comment: no, its working for 2 iteration after that its failing even though the condition is true, its not going inside the loop

Comment: @user3168178 Can we see the loop you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with string comparison try

```
$('#next_page').click(function () {
    var t = +$('#totalPages').val();//or parseInt($('#totalPages').val())
    var c = +$('#currentPage').val();//or parseInt($('#currentPage').val())
    if (c <= t) {
        var pageNo = c + 1;
        var sector = $('#sectorValue').val();
        var state = $('#states').val();
```

Comment: @user3168178 you could simplify the condition ot `if (c <= t) {`

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` always return a string value, which on arithmetic comparison behaves not in the way expected. So always before arithmetic operations convert these values, using:

```
parseInt(stringValue);
```

or simply putting `+` operator with string value which convert this string value to integer:

```
var t = +$('#totalPages').val();
```

you may also change your condition, simpler and readable:

```
if(c <= t){
```